# Does it make sense to perform PCA on dataset after SVD first?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svd

I have a data set of size (4700, 10000). First I performed SVD on this data and obtained 100 SVD components, so my data set is now (4700, 100). Then I performed PCA on such reduced data and obtained 4 components and did the visualization with such 4  components of PCA. As both SVD and PCA are the dimensionality reduction techniques, I was curious is it safe to perform SVD and then PCA?

In addition, when I do PCA on data set obtained after SVD the visualization gives more meaningful results than from PCA alone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did not find anything related in this link.

Comment: It was a hint to move the question there, as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com and http://scicomp.stackexchange.com would be the obvious alternatives.